# Linq query to compose grouped collection by sum of other collection

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have amounts that should be spent on related balances. I need to fit each amount with a proper balance. The amounts that cannot be spent because of balance is exhausted should be discarded/not selected.

I have two collections:

```
var balances = new [] { 0.345, 1.234, 9.340, ... };
var amounts = new [] { 0.011, 0.122, 1.230, 0.123, ... };
```

I need to group the amounts by sum up to each value in balances with this final result:

```
var result =
{
    group1 = { 0.011, 0.122 } // 0.133 sum < 0.345 balance
    group2 = { 1.230 } // 1.230 sum < 1.234 balance
    group3 = { 0.123, ... } // sum < 9.340 balance,
    ...
}
```

Balances collection should be ordered by descending before.
Amounts should be fit with balance by the way as it going in the collection.
How I can do this by the linq or using the iterators and related calculations is a better way? Thanks.

Current logic without linq:

```
IOrderedEnumerable<Address> addresses = addressesList
    .Where(value => value.Balance > 0)
    .OrderByDescending(value => value.Balance);

List<SendTask> selectedTasks = new List<SendTask>();
int lastSelectedTaskIndex = 0;
SendTask[] tasks = tasksToProcess.ToArray();
int tasksCount = tasksToProcess.Count();

foreach (Address address in addresses)
{
    decimal balance = 0;
                
    for(int i = lastSelectedTaskIndex; i < tasksCount; i++)
    {
        SendTask task = tasks[i];
        balance += task.TransactionAmount;

        if (balance < address.Balance)
        {
            selectedTasks.Add(task);
            lastSelectedTaskIndex++;
        }
        else 
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}

notSelectedTasks = tasksToProcess.Except(selectedTasks).Select(task => task.TaskId);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and where did you stuck?

Comment: @PeterCsala I've updated the description. I'm stuck with composing linq because I have no idea how I can achieve this.

Comment: Have you tried to achieve it without LINQ? Simply by using `for` or `foreach` loop(s)?

Comment: @PeterCsala, yea, sure, with foreach there is no problem. I want to know, is it possible with linq or not?

Comment: Then I would suggest to share with us that code as well.

Comment: @PeterCsala, I have added it to description

Comment: I'm not a LINQ guru but I think `GroupBy` was not designed for this kind of use case. The operator can decide for each element that it should belong to which group. So it does not use an *accumulator*  (like in case of `Aggregate`) to store information about the previous elements. [Most of the overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-5.0) anticipate `keySelector`, `resultSelector` and/or `comparer`.

Comment: @PeterCsala, thanks, your answer was comprehensive.

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem with `Aggregate`?